# Listing all files from Google Drive

Tags: php, google-oauth, google-api-php-client, google-drive-api

I would like to list all the files from my Google drive to my "DriveFiles.php" file where I can display the files and its details. I am a beginner so a complete code will be helpful. Thanks.

My code:

```
<?php


require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/io/Google_HttpRequest.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php';

// initialize a client with application credentials and required scopes.
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId('CLIENT_ID');
$client->setClientSecret('CLIENT_SECRET');
$client->setRedirectUri('REDIRECT_URI');
$client->setScopes(array(
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'));
$client->setUseObjects(true);


if (isset($_GET['code']))
   {
   session_start();
   print_r($_SESSION);
   $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
   $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
   $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
   // initialize the drive service with the client.
   $services = new Google_DriveService($client);
   retrieveAllFiles($services);    

  }



 if(!$client->getAccessToken()){
   $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
   echo '<a class="login" href="'.$authUrl.'">Login</a>';
   }


 function retrieveAllFiles($service) {
   $result = array();
   $pageToken = NULL;

          do {
            try {
              $parameters = array();
              if ($pageToken) {
                $parameters['pageToken'] = $pageToken;
              }
              $files = $service->files->listFiles($parameters);

              $result = array_merge($result, $files->getItems());
              $pageToken = $files->getNextPageToken();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
              print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
              $pageToken = NULL;
            }
          } while ($pageToken);
          return $result;
        }
        ?>
```

When I execute the code I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Exception' with message 'Cant
>   add services after having authenticated' in
>   D:\GT_local\Public\google-api-php-client\src\Google_Client.php:115
>   Stack trace: #0
>   D:\GT_local\Public\google-api-php-client\src\contrib\Google_DriveService.php(1258):
>   Google_Client->addService('drive', 'v2') #1
>   D:\GT_local\Public\quickstart.php(55):
>   Google_DriveService->__construct(Object(Google_Client)) #2 {main}
>   thrown in
>   "FILE_LOCATION(C://google-api-php-client\src\Google_Client.php on line
>   115)"

How can I fix this.

Comment: I would start by using the newest client lib. The one you are using is no longer being developed upon.  https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

Answer (score 0):

Try starting the session in the top of the script, and try to do all authentication before you have to do any operation. Also use the most recent API so you can use this libraries:

```
require_once '/src/Google/autoload.php';
require_once '/src/Google/Client.php';
require_once '/src/Google/Service/Oauth2.php';
require_once '/src/Google/Service/Drive.php';
```